# Why does merging two sorted linked Lists work - since when we do l4=l4.next, l4 points to a different object on heap, than l3. - C#

Tags: c#, linked-list, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am sorry that this question is a little elaborate - but I couldn't find a better way of asking this question. Thanks much for all the help!

Following is the method I wrote for merging two sorted linked lists - (`MergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2)`). Following is the entire program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinkedList
{
     public class ListNode
    {
        public int val;
        public ListNode next;
        public ListNode(int val = 0, ListNode next = null)
        {
            this.val = val;
            this.next = next;
        }
     }


    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListNode list1= new ListNode(1, new ListNode(2, new ListNode(4, null)));
            ListNode list2 = new ListNode(1, new ListNode(3, new ListNode(4, null)));
            ListNode list3 = MergeTwoLists(list1,list2);
        }

        public static ListNode MergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) 
        {
            if (list1 == null)
                return list2;
            else if (list2 == null)
                return list1;
            ListNode **l3 = new ListNode(0,null)**;
            ListNode **l4 = l3**;
            while (list1 != null && list2 != null)//list1 = 1->2->4->null
            {                               //list2 = 1->3->4->null
                if (list1.val <= list2.val)
                {
                    l4.next = list1;
                    list1 = list1.next;//after this statement, list1 now = 2->4->null. 
                }
                else
                {
                    l4.next = list2;
                    list2 = list2.next;
                }
                **l4 = l4.next**;//this should cause a problem in merging two lists, but doesn't.
            }
            l4.next=list1==null?list2:list1;
            return l3.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here is my question -

There are three bolded lines in the method - `MergeTwoLists`, above (stackoverflow does not allow bolding a code snippet, so the bolded code snippet was surrounded by double asterisx).

The three bolded lines in the method - `MergeTwoLists` - are:

1. **l3 = new ListNode(0,null)**
2. **l4 = l3**
3. **l4 = l4.next**

In line 1. above, `l3` reference variable is on the stack, and points to the `ListNode` object `0->null`, on the heap.
In line 2. above, `l4` reference variable is on the stack, and is assigned the `l3` reference variable. So both, `l4` and `l3` point to the same `ListNode` object on the heap - `0->null`.
Line 3. above should cause a problem in merging two lists. Because, when we do `l4 = l4.next` - `l4` is assigned a reference to a new memory location on the heap. **And the link between `l3` and `l4` is broken** (meaning, they now refer to different memory locations on the heap - instead of referring to the same memory location on the heap). Then how is it that l3 is able to merge the two linked lists (list1 and list2), perfectly?

- So, let us see, what happens, when we initially enter the `while` loop in the method - `MergeTwoLists`.

1. Originally, when we enter the `MergeTwoLists` method, `list1` reference variable is on the stack, and points to the following `ListNode` object on the heap - `1->2->4->null`.
   2.Similarly, originally, when we enter the `MergeTwoLists` method, `list2` reference variable is on the stack, and points to the following `ListNode` object on the heap - `1->3->4->null`.

Now, when we enter the `while` loop the first time (in the method `MergeTwoLists`),`list1` points to `1->2->4->null` and `list2` points to `1->3->4->null`. And since `list1.val == list2.val` is `true`, we go into the `if` statement of the `while` loop.

In the `if` statement, the first line is `l4.next = list1`. After executing `l4.next=list1`, the `l4` reference variable points to `0->1->2->4->null` on the heap. And since the `l3` reference variable `=` the `l4` reference variable, `l3` on the stack also points to the same location on heap, as `l4`. That is `l3` also points to `0->1->2->4->null` on the heap.

The next statement after this, in the `if` block is: `list1 = list1.next`, and the `list1` reference variable now points to the following `ListNode` object on the heap - `2->4->null`.

So the status of `l4` and `l3`, after the end of the `if` block, the first time are:
`l4` reference variable points to the `ListNode` object `0->1->2->4->null` on the heap.
And, `l3` reference variable also points to the same `ListNode` object `0->1->2->4->null` on the heap.

Next, we skip the else block (since we have gone into the `if` block). And execute the statement right below the else block - namely: **l4 = l4.next**.

The above statement - **l4 = l4.next** - is exactly where things got confusing for me.
in the above statement - `l4 = l4.next` - the reference variable `l4` is **assigned** a reference to a new object on the heap (that is, it is assigned  `l4.next`).

Since `l4` is now assigned a reference to a new object, **the link between l3 and l4 is broken**.
That is, `l4` now points to new `ListNode` object on the heap -  `1->2->4->null`.
But, `l3` points to the original `ListNode` object, that was there on the heap - `0->1->2->4->null`.

- Now, let us see what happens, when we go into the while loop, the second time -

When we enter the while loop the second time:
`list1` points to the `ListNode` object  - `2->4->null` on the heap.
And, `list2` points to the `ListNode` object - `1->3->4->null` on the heap.

When we enter the while loop the second time, `list1!=null` `= true` `&&` `list2!=null` `= true`, so we enter the while loop again.
This time, list1.val = 2 and list2.val = 1 - so, we won't go into the `if` block and will instead go into the `else` block.

The first statement in the `else` block is - `l4.next = list2`. This statement will result in the following:
`l4` reference variable will now point to the following `ListNode` object on the heap - `1->1->3->4->null`.

The next line after this in the `else` block is: `list2 = list2.next`. When we execute `list2 = list2.next`, the `list2` reference variable will point to the following `ListNode` object on the heap - `3->4->null`.

Again, just after the else block, we meet the statement - `l4 = l4.next`. And the `l4` reference variable will now point to the following `ListNode` object on the heap - `1->3->4->null`.

**My question is**: How is `l3` **further** getting effected by changes to `l4`? - since the link between `l3` and `l4` got broken as soon as we assigned a new object reference to `l4` (that is, as soon as we did `l4 = l4.next`, the first time at the end of the `while` loop)?

**Note**: By link getting broken, I mean `l3` and `l4` now do not point to the same object on the heap. But now point to different objects on the heap.

But, when I run the above code in visual studio, `l3` follows `l4` - i.e. `l3` creates a merged sorted linked list perfectly.

**Actual correct result**: When the program runs in visual studio, it returns the `l3` reference variable that points to the following `ListNode` object on heap - `0->1->1->2->3->4->4->null`.
**Expected result, by my logic here**: when we return `l3`, it should return `0->1->2->4->null`.

**To reiterate my logic**: it is the following code snippet, that messes up merging of the two linked lists in sorted order - `l4 = l4.next`. We meet this code snippet, the first time, when we enter the `while` loop the first time (and henceforth).
And before we enter the `while` loop the first time, everything is fine - `l3` points to `0->null` on the heap. And since `l4 = l3`, `l4` also points to the same location on the heap (i.e. `0->null`).
When we go inside the `while` loop the first time, things are still fine - we enter the `if` block in the `while` loop and there we hit `l4.next = list1`. This makes `l4` point to `0->1->2->4->null` (on the heap). And since `l4 = l3` - `l3` points to the same location as `l4` - `0->1->2->4->null` (on the heap).
But, as soon as we reach the line of code `l4 = l4.next` the first time - `l4` now points to a new object on the heap (`1->2->4->null`). And `l3` points to the original object on the heap (`0->1->2->4->null`). From here on, whatever changes are made to `l4` won't be reflected in `l3` (since `l3` points to a different memory location on heap - and `l4` keeps pointing to different memory locations on the heap, from here on).

So, how come `l3` in the end shows the merged lists in completely sorted order? - `l3` should only be `0->1->2->4->null`, at the end of the method. So how does `l3` give the correct sorted result? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Firstly, [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](https://ericlippert.com/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/), it's all about *reference* semantics, which you get by using `class` rather than `struct`.

Comment: Essentially, the root object referred to by `l3` still points to the next node, which you then modify. There is no broken link. The statement "That is `l3` also points to 0->1->2->4->null on the heap." should be "That is the *object pointed to by* `l3` also points to 0->1->2->4->null on the heap." and that object remains, and was modified via `l4`. It's the objects *themselves* which do the pointing, it's double indirection.

Comment: Side note: self-trolling by selecting awful variable names causes (correspondingly self-inflicted) wounds. If you would name the variables in a meaningful way the code would be soooo much easier to understand even to you as the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as exhaustively pointed out, [**The Stack Is An Implementation Detail**](https://ericlippert.com/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/), it's *completely irrelevant* to most discussions about reference and value types.

It's actually all about reference semantics, which you get by using `class`, a opposed to value semantics with `struct`. In other words: reference types are always passed by reference, a variable of such an object *points to* the object rather than *being* the object.

---

To come back to your question:

Essentially, the root/head object referred to by `l3` always points to the head of the list. `l4` represents the *current* node. **Better variable names would have made this easier to understand.**

`l3` always points to the head *object*, this object can still access other linked objects using its `next` variable, which is *also* a pointer (because of reference semantics).

`l4` is first assigned to this node. When you modify `l4.next`, you are also modifying the *same object* as `l3.next`. Then when you assign `l4 = l4.next;` you can also access that node via `l3.next.next`.

**There is no broken link.** The statement "That is l3 also points to 0->1->2->4->null on the heap." should be "That is *the object pointed to by* l3 also points to 0->1->2->4->null." and that object remains, and was modified via l4.

It's the objects themselves which do the pointing, you therefore have double indirection: `l3` variable points to a node, which itself points to `l4` which points to another node and so on.

So when it loops back again, `l4` now points to the second node in the linked list. `l4` is modified so that it then points to the next node according to the merge criteria. Then we again assign `l4 = l4.next;` so that we can attach the fourth node to the third.

Answer (score 0):

I walked through the code, and am pasting my answer here - in case if it helps someone else:
[image]